# reverse dns configuration not working

Tags: reverse-dns

I am configuring my reverse dns server, after installation then I run the following:

```
nslookup 110.74.133.89
Server:         192.168.101.4
Address:        192.168.101.4#53

** server can't find 89.133.74.110.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

host 110.74.133.89
Host 89.133.74.110.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Can anyone help me to figure out my error.
Thanks and best regards

name.conf

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

acl "trusted" {
        110.74.133.89;    # ns1 - can be set to localhost
        110.74.133.90;    # ns2
};
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 110.74.133.89; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-transfer { localhost; 110.74.133.89; };
        allow-query     { localhost; 110.74.133.0/24; };
        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};


zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/named/named.conf.local";
```

Forward zone file below

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA  ns1.anisehq.com. root.anisehq.com. (
                                2015180801      ; serial
                                      3600      ; refresh
                                      1800      ; retry
                                    604800      ; expire
                                     86400  )   ; minimum
; Name server's

@      IN      NS      ns1.anisehq.com.
@      IN      NS      ns2.anisehq.com.

; Name server hostname to IP resolve.

@          IN    A   110.74.133.89
@          IN    A   110.74.133.90

;  Hosts in this domain

ns1     IN      A       110.74.133.89
ns2     IN      A       110.74.133.90
```

Reverse zone file below

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA  ns1.anisehq.com.    root.anisehq.com. (
                                2015180801      ; serial
                                     3600       ; refresh
                                     1800       ; retry
                                   604800       ; expire
                                    86400 )     ; minimum TTL
;  Name Server's

@   IN NS ns1.anisehq.com.
@   IN NS ns2.anisehq.com.


; Name Server Hostname to IP resolve.

ns1 IN A 110.74.133.89
ns2 IN A 110.74.133.90

; Hosts in Domain

89 IN PTR ns1.anisehq.com.
90 IN PTR ns2.anisehq.com.
```

Comment: Not unless you show us how it's configured, we can't.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have posted my configuration files bellow.

Answer (score 1):

The name you looked up, `89.133.74.110.in-addr.arpa`, is part of the `133.74.110.in-addr.arpa` zone delegated to the nameservers `ns1.aims.my` (`110.74.128.71`) and `ns2.aims.my` (`110.74.128.72`).

```
133.74.110.in-addr.arpa. 86400  IN      NS      ns1.aims.my.
133.74.110.in-addr.arpa. 86400  IN      NS      ns2.aims.my.
```

Unless the resolver server you queried when you tested this, `192.168.101.4`, has some special configuration to override what the rest of us see for this zone, it seems like `NXDOMAIN` is actually the expected result considering that `ns{1,2}.aims.my` do not have such a name in their `133.74.110.in-addr.arpa` zone.

You will need to get the reverse zone for your IP network delegated to your own nameservers before anyone will ask your nameservers about this.

If, on the other hand, you are not actually interested in what data the masses will see but instead just want to check what your own authoritative servers answer, you should direct the query directly to one of your own nameservers.

(Looking at the zone files it looks like those could work, however it's not possible to tell if the config is correct as you only included the base config file but use `include` to reference other additional files with more config. Based on the filenames alone, I would guess the zone definitions may be in `named.conf.local`.)